# como conectaor hickvision a odoo

Tags: odoo, biometrico

Hola estoy tratando de conectar una terminal facial para asistencia de la marca hikvision a mi sistema de odoo pero estoy tratando de hacerlo desde un modulo que se llama hr_zk_atendance pero no logro conectarlo al meter la ip y el puerto de la terminal me manda el siguiente mensaje:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

y aqui esta el codigo donde esta haciendo la conexion con el dispositivo

```
import pytz
import sys
import datetime
import logging
import binascii

from . import zklib
from .zkconst import *
from struct import unpack
from odoo import api, fields, models
from odoo import _
 from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
  _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
try:
from zk import ZK, const
except ImportError:
_logger.error("Please Install pyzk library.")

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class HrAttendance(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.attendance'

device_id = fields.Char(string='Biometric Device ID')
```

class ZkMachine(models.Model):
_name = 'zk.machine'

```
name = fields.Char(string='Machine IP', required=True)
port_no = fields.Integer(string='Port No', required=True)
address_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Working Address')
company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', string='Company', default=lambda self: 
self.env.user.company_id.id)

def device_connect(self, zk):
    try:
        conn = zk.connect()
        return conn
    except:
        return False

def clear_attendance(self):
    for info in self:
        try:
            machine_ip = info.name
            zk_port = info.port_no
            timeout = 30
            try:
                zk = ZK(machine_ip, port=zk_port, timeout=timeout, password=0,
```

force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)
except NameError:
raise UserError(*("Please install it with 'pip3 install pyzk'."))
conn = self.device_connect(zk)
if conn:
conn.enable_device()
clear_data = zk.get_attendance()
if clear_data:
# conn.clear_attendance()
self.*cr.execute("""delete from zk_machine_attendance""")
conn.disconnect()
raise UserError(*('Attendance Records Deleted.'))
else:
raise UserError(*('Unable to clear Attendance log. Are you sure attendance log is not empty.'))
else:
raise UserError(
_('Unable to connect to Attendance Device. Please use Test Connection button to verify.'))
except:
raise ValidationError(
'Unable to clear Attendance log. Are you sure attendance device is connected & record is not empty.')

```
def getSizeUser(self, zk):
    """Checks a returned packet to see if it returned CMD_PREPARE_DATA,
    indicating that data packets are to be sent

    Returns the amount of bytes that are going to be sent"""
    command = unpack('HHHH', zk.data_recv[:8])[0]
    if command == CMD_PREPARE_DATA:
        size = unpack('I', zk.data_recv[8:12])[0]
        print("size", size)
        return size
    else:
        return False

def zkgetuser(self, zk):
    """Start a connection with the time clock"""
    try:
        users = zk.get_users()
        print(users)
        return users
    except:
        return False

@api.model
def cron_download(self):
    machines = self.env['zk.machine'].search([])
    for machine in machines :
        machine.download_attendance()
    
def download_attendance(self):
    _logger.info("++++++++++++Cron Executed++++++++++++++++++++++")
    zk_attendance = self.env['zk.machine.attendance']
    att_obj = self.env['hr.attendance']
    for info in self:
        machine_ip = info.name
        zk_port = info.port_no
        timeout = 15
        try:
            zk = ZK(machine_ip, port=zk_port, timeout=timeout, password=0, force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)
        except NameError:
            raise UserError(_("Pyzk module not Found. Please install it with 'pip3 install pyzk'."))
        conn = self.device_connect(zk)
        if conn:
            # conn.disable_device() #Device Cannot be used during this time.
            try:
                user = conn.get_users()
            except:
                user = False
            try:
                attendance = conn.get_attendance()
            except:
                attendance = False
            if attendance:
                for each in attendance:
                    atten_time = each.timestamp
                    atten_time = datetime.strptime(atten_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                    local_tz = pytz.timezone(
                        self.env.user.partner_id.tz or 'GMT')
                    local_dt = local_tz.localize(atten_time, is_dst=None)
                    utc_dt = local_dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)
                    utc_dt = utc_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                    atten_time = datetime.strptime(
                        utc_dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                    atten_time = fields.Datetime.to_string(atten_time)
                    if user:
                        for uid in user:
                            if uid.user_id == each.user_id:
                                get_user_id = self.env['hr.employee'].search(
                                    [('device_id', '=', each.user_id)])
                                if get_user_id:
                                    duplicate_atten_ids = zk_attendance.search(
                                        [('device_id', '=', each.user_id), ('punching_time', '=', atten_time)])
                                    if duplicate_atten_ids:
                                        continue
                                    else:
                                        zk_attendance.create({'employee_id': get_user_id.id,
                                                              'device_id': each.user_id,
                                                              'attendance_type': str(each.status),
                                                              'punch_type': str(each.punch),
                                                              'punching_time': atten_time,
                                                              'address_id': info.address_id.id})
                                        att_var = att_obj.search([('employee_id', '=', get_user_id.id),
                                                                  ('check_out', '=', False)])
                                        print('ddfcd', str(each.status))
                                        if each.punch == 0: #check-in
                                            if not att_var:
                                                att_obj.create({'employee_id': get_user_id.id,
                                                                'check_in': atten_time})
                                        if each.punch == 1: #check-out
                                            if len(att_var) == 1:
                                                att_var.write({'check_out': atten_time})
                                            else:
                                                att_var1 = att_obj.search([('employee_id', '=', get_user_id.id)])
                                                if att_var1:
                                                    att_var1[-1].write({'check_out': atten_time})

                                else:
                                    print('ddfcd', str(each.status))
                                    print('user', uid.name)
                                    employee = self.env['hr.employee'].create(
                                        {'device_id': each.user_id, 'name': uid.name})
                                    zk_attendance.create({'employee_id': employee.id,
                                                          'device_id': each.user_id,
                                                          'attendance_type': str(each.status),
                                                          'punch_type': str(each.punch),
                                                          'punching_time': atten_time,
                                                          'address_id': info.address_id.id})
                                    att_obj.create({'employee_id': employee.id,
                                                    'check_in': atten_time})
                            else:
                                pass
                # zk.enableDevice()
                conn.disconnect
                return True
            else:
                raise UserError(_('Unable to get the attendance log, please try again later.'))
        else:
            raise UserError(_('Unable to connect, please check the parameters and network connections.'))
```

ese es el codigo que tengo para la conexion no se si la conexion este fallando o no de conexion porqiue este modulko solo sea para dispositivos zk
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/egika.png

Comment: Ese modulo solo es para aparatos Zk. Debes buscar SDK para hickivision.